# DVI to DisplayPort, at 1080p@144hz

Tags: display-port, video-adapters, dvi

I have two monitors: Acer GN246HL. Each has a D-Sub, DVI and HDMI. My current video card (GTX 770) has two DVI slots, so this is not a problem I can get both at running 1080p 144hz.

However, newer video cards have one or zero DVI slots. They mostly have DisplayPort ports, which my monitors don't support.

So I'm looking for an adapter that would allow me to use my monitors with newer video cards, to output at 1920x1080@144hz (Exactly like I am doing right now with the 770GTX and two DVI connections). I'm thinking DVI-D to DisplayPort.

Are there such adapters, and are they reliable?

Answer (score 1):

While there are DisplayPort to DVI-D Dual Link dongles, they appear to be quite expensive and require USB Power to function correctly.

[This](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812400320&cm_re=active_dual_link_displayport-_-12-400-320-_-Product) dongle from StarTech should support a DisplayPort input and convert to Dual Link DVI-D, which is needed for 144Hz at 1080p.

Note that the cheaper dongles available for DP to DVI are either Single Link or do not have the bandwidth to output at 1080p 144Hz.

Comment: The important thing here is that cheap adapters use the passive [DisplayPort++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) which only supports single link, while expensive adapters are active.

Comment: While this is probably one of the few available choices the website says "1920 x 1080 @ 120 Hz" is the max @120hz, and does seem to support 144hz as the OP wants.